# Як передавати носовий звук [ŋ] в словах англомовного походження, що закінчуються на "ing"?

Tags: запозичені-слова

#### Засновок 1:

Літера "g" в інґових закінченнях не вимовляється, замість неї вимовляється [носовий (назальний) звук [ŋ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_nasal).

#### Засновок 2:

У [правилах транслітерування **власних назв**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307020619/http://sips.gov.ua/ua/transliteruvannja.html) з анґлійської мови кажуть звук [ŋ] передавати або як "нґ" в кінці слова і як "н" в усіх інших випадках.

#### Засновок 3:

Купу таких слів транслітерують ніби хаотично, наприклад: [майнінг](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3), [булінг](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F), [петинг](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) тощо.

#### Отже:

Якщо ці запозичення відбуваються згідно з певним правилом, будь ласка, поділіться ним.

Якщо ні - будь ласка, поділіться правилом, яке б охоплювало не тільки власні назви, а загалом транслітерування при запозиченні іноземних слів. Сам поки знайти не можу.

Якщо такого правила не існує, скажіть, будь ласка, як, все-таки, правильно запозичувати такі слова просто з точки зору лоґіки й схожих випадків.